# Front driver squeal

Tags: suspension

2010 Jeep GC limited 4x4 recently purchased used. I replaced front bilateral wheel bearings, rotors, pads, upper & lower control arms along with cv joint on driver side. Dust plate was completely rotted so removed unable to purchase locally & needed to get it all back together before the 7 day arrival of new....new tires & alignment completed. I have noticed a squeal on driver side when I make right turns & slight squeal with bumps, I do not have a lift & cannot seem to pinpoint it on my own on mere jack stands any thoughts???? I've taking the wheel off checked rotors thought maybe slider was rubbing no indications, no sign of anything causing a rub. power steering fluid at norm level, I'd hope brand new cv is properly lubricated, im far from a mechanic so hoping im missing something simple any suggestions would be greatful...the squeal resembles a bad belt if that helps???